# deadlock analize with SQL Server Profiler - IX Lock while executing select statements

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I run SQL Server Profiler and saw that I have some deadlocks.
When I opened deadlock graph I could see that only select statements are in that graph. 
For many pagelocks waiter and owner has the same "S" mode.
For some pagelocks  owner has "IX" mode but when I looked at that process execution stack - it is select statement with isolationlevel="read committed (2)".

Here I have two questions:

1. How could it happen that select statement causes deadlocks?
2. How could it happen that select statement has IX mode?

Comment: And that's not a select ... into clause or something with strange locking hints?

Comment: No, it's normal select (query with union of two selects). It is executed with hibernate.

Comment: Could it be that SQL Server Profiler does not provide full deadlock graph?